# Why is my code not writing into the .ini file?

Tags: c#, .net, ini

I'm currently writing some of my first codes in c#. I want my code to save some values (used for settings) into an .ini file in the profile roaming folder. There are not errors. But when I run my code, there are no changes in the .ini file.

My Code:

```
private void LoadSettings()
{
    var userprofile_location = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + @"\Appdata\Roaming\GameCentral";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(userprofile_location);
    File.Create(userprofile_location + @"\settings.ini");
    IniFile settings = new IniFile(userprofile_location + @"\settings.ini");
    settings.Write("1","PFAD","Icons");
}
```

The Code from StacksOverflow to use the .ini's:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace GameCentral
{
    class IniFile
    {
        string Path;
        string EXE = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;

        [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string Section, string Key, string Value, string FilePath);

        [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string Section, string Key, string Default, StringBuilder RetVal, int Size, string FilePath);

        public IniFile(string IniPath = null)
        {
            Path = new FileInfo(IniPath ?? EXE + ".ini").FullName;
        }

        public string Read(string Key, string Section = null)
        {
            var RetVal = new StringBuilder(255);
            GetPrivateProfileString(Section ?? EXE, Key, "", RetVal, 255, Path);
            return RetVal.ToString();
        }

        public void Write(string Key, string Value, string Section = null)
        {
            WritePrivateProfileString(Section ?? EXE, Key, Value, Path);
        }

        public void DeleteKey(string Key, string Section = null)
        {
            Write(Key, null, Section ?? EXE);
        }

        public void DeleteSection(string Section = null)
        {
            Write(null, null, Section ?? EXE);
        }

        public bool KeyExists(string Key, string Section = null)
        {
            return Read(Key, Section).Length > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Solution:

I found out, that i don't need to create the ini file. Code would be like:

```
private void LoadSettings()
{
    var userprofile_location = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + @"\Appdata\Roaming\GameCentral";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(userprofile_location);
    //File.Create(userprofile_location + @"\settings.ini");
    var settings = new IniFile(userprofile_location + @"\settings.ini");
    settings.Write("1","path","Icons");
}
```

Comment: You should edit your original post rather than commenting the fix

Comment: when I try your code, it simply deletes the content of the entire ini file

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, If you find your answer, you should post it as an answer, not just by editing your post. Good Luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void LoadSettings()
{
    var userprofile_location = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + @"\Appdata\Roaming\GameCentral";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(userprofile_location);
    //File.Create(userprofile_location + @"\settings.ini");
    var settings = new IniFile(userprofile_location + @"\settings.ini");
    settings.Write("1","path","Icons");
}
```

It was just that one line...